# Google direction API travel time is different from live google map

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google direction API in my project now I also need the estimated travel time between two places including traffic. So I am passing the departure time : `Thursday 07-January-2016 time: 14:10 PM ( 1452175200 )` as per the google direction API documentation.

See the difference between live google map and google direction API and suggest if I am doing wrong anything.

```
Live google map response: (Thursday 07-January-2016 time: 14:10 PM )

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los+Angeles+International+Airport,+1+World+Way,+Los+Angeles,+CA+90045,+United+States/Beverly+Hills,+CA/@34.0077875,-118.4795875,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m17!4m16!1m5!1m1!1s0x80c2b0d213b24fb5:0x77a87b57698badf1!2m2!1d-118.40853!2d33.9415889!1m5!1m1!1s0x80c2bc04d6d147ab:0xd6c7c379fd081ed1!2m2!1d-118.4003563!2d34.0736204!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1452175200

typically 28 min - 1 h 15 min

typically 35 min - 1 h 10 min

02:14 PM to 03:28 PM 1 h 14 min

****************************

Google direction API:

//Source address
$a = 'Los Angeles International Airport, 1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA 90045, United States'; 
//Destination address
$b = 'Beverly Wilshire, Beverly Hills (A Four Seasons Hotel), 9500 Wilshire Boulevard, Beverly Hills, CA 90212, United
        States';

//Pass source and destination address in google map API for PESSIMISTIC
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1452175200&mode=driving&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
//output:  duration_in_traffic =  38 mins

//Pass source and destination address in google map API for OPTIMISTIC
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1452175200&mode=driving&traffic_model=optimistic&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
//output:  duration_in_traffic = 27 mins

//Pass source and destination address in google map API for BEST_GUESS
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1452175200&mode=driving&traffic_model=best_guess&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
//output:  duration_in_traffic = 30 mins
```

Both  response must be same or approximate, but here we can see the huge difference. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Do you provide a **Google Maps API for Work** API key?

Comment: Yes  key =>> 

AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs

Comment: That doesn't tell me if this is a "pro" key (API for Work customers). By the way, you should avoid giving your API key like that. If you correctly defined the referrers then there should be no issue but I'd say it's better to keep it for yourself...

Comment: Ok, should I use pro key(I have to add my credit card and then should generate it again)?

Comment: Sorry I might have mis-read the documentation here. It actually says it works "only if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps API for Work client ID". So a standard API key should actually work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Timezone Complexity

The API takes departure_time in UTC.

And it seems that the **live Google map takes the timezone of the origin**, when 'Depart at' is chosen (and maybe of destination, when 'Arrive by' is selected).

#### Source of error

Your assumption was that the live Google map time is in IST.

Your live google map response for 07-January-2016 14:10 PM actually means 2:10 PM in Los Angeles, which translates to Thursday, 7 January 2016, 22:00:00 UTC (and departure_time = 1452204600).

#### Result verification

Live Google map results for Jan 7, 2016, 2:10 PM:

- typically 28 min - 1 h 5 min
- typically 35 min - 1 h
- typically 30 min - 1 h 5 min

Results obtained from API for corresponding time (departure_time = 1452204600):

- best_guess: 39 mins
- pessimistic: 1 hour 1 min
- optimistic: 28 mins

PS: To get live map results corresponding to your API results, select 'Depart at'=6:00AM.

Comment: Funny, we came up with the same answer at the same time... Just as a side note, Los Angeles is PST not IST which stands for "India, Ireland or Israel Standard Time", unless I missed something ;-)

Comment: @MrUpsidown hehe yes! And I meant Indian Standard Time only (because the questioner made the search sitting in India, hence his assumption).
(Depart at 6am in the PS is in PST).

Comment: Ok I have taken address of India and departure time is 08-Jan-2016 6:30 PM (1452277800) now you can see the same result for this.

Comment: Google map result: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/LIG+Square,+Old+Palasia,+Indore,+Madhya+Pradesh,+India/Bhawarkuan+Police+Station,+AB+Road,+Bhavarkuan,+Indra+Puri+Colony,+Indore,+Madhya+Pradesh,+India/@22.7130291,75.8599915,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m16!4m15!1m5!1m1!1s0x3962fd4f37bcbb7d:0xc1c2490e471e5a71!2m2!1d75.8898349!2d22.7327916!1m5!1m1!1s0x3962fce50167a359:0x6585928e0ae7d0b3!2m2!1d75.8674657!2d22.6921907!2m2!7e2!8j1452279600

Comment: And actual API result: pessimistic==>> 12 min, optimistic==> 11 min, best_guess=> 11 min. but live google map is showing different time for different route. Like first one: 16 min to 26 min || 16 min to 28 min || and 18 min to 30 min.

Comment: Google maps use local time. So 08-Jan-2016 6:30 PM will be in Indian Standard Time (IST) for this search in India. In UTC it will be 08-Jan-2016 01:00 PM, which means departure time = 1452258000. (Your value 1452277800 is 08-Jan-2016 6:30 PM in UTC).

Comment: For your search link, depart at is 7:00PM (IST) = 01:30PM (UTC) ==> departure_at = 1452259800.
Try again with these parameters: origin=LIG+Square%2C+Old+Palasia%2C+Indore%2C+Madhya+Pradesh%2C+India&destination=Bhawarkuan+Police+Station%2C+AB+Road%2C+Bhavarkuan%2C+Indra+Puri+Colony%2C+Indore%2C+Madhya+Pradesh%2C+India&mode=driving&traffic_model=pessimistic&departure_time=1452259800&key=yourkey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99900/discussion-between-raghbendra-nayak-and-jatinderjit).

Comment: I don't know what is the purpose of your code, but this might be of some help to you if you dynamically need to find the timezone https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a chance to try your code but I suspect the issue might be with the `departure_time` parameter.

`1452175200` is January 7. 2016 - 14:00:00 — this is correct

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=en) specifies that *You can specify the time as an integer in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.*

It is not very clear, but I think the API expects you to give the time as UTC.

Since Los Angeles is UTC-8, you should adapt the timestamp accordingly.

Try it and let me know!